# GNAT GPS on the fly syntax checking and getting the best out of the IDE

Tags: ada, gnat-gps

I've started using GPS for coding Ada at work - does anyone have any tips for getting the best out of the IDE? or any plugins I should be aware of?

For example is there a way to enable on the fly syntax/type checking - of the sorts you get in eclipse/visual studio where errors are underlined as you go?

Also what are people's general opinions on GNAT Workbench compared to GPS?

thanks

Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GPS does not have a from of background syntax checking and that is by design. The idea behind GPS is that it is the compiler who decides what code is correct and what code is not correct. It means that if you want to know if your code is correct or not you have to compile it. On a Windows computer the short cut key for that is SHIFT+F4 and will only compile the specification or body file you are currently editing. Pressing F4 will compile your whole project. You will save time by using SHIFT+F4.

Another interesting feature is that the GPS uses cross-reference (XREF) information when navigation through the code. For example, let's say you would like to find all the places in your code where a specific subprogram is called. In GPS (GNAT PRO), right click on the subprogram you are interested in a press Find references. In the GPS GNAT Libre version you don't have a menu when right clicking in your code. In this case go to the Navigate menu and click on Find references there. If the GPS does not find any references and you know that the subprogram is used in the application it means that the XREF information needs to be updated. You may compile the whole application by F4 since the XREF information will be generated along with the binary that is produced. If you go to Edit and click on Key shortcuts you can set up a short cut key to generate the XREF information only. You may also find several interesting features there that you can set up a short cut key for.

The cross-reference information (XREF) is also used for refactoring (GNAT PRO specific functionality). It often works well for changing variable and subprogram names. Just make sure the cross-reference information is up to date!

Code snippets in GPS are also useful. You use them by writing a keyword followed by CTRL+O (not zero, O as in Orwell). To see the code snippets you can choose between go to Edit and click on Aliases. You can also create your own Aliases and code snippets to become a more productive Ada Software Engineer.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I do not think that GPS has a form of background syntax checking like Eclipse does, at least I haven't found it.

I wrote a small sized terminal program in GPS as my first Ada program and my opinion of it is generally negative.

The browser is very confusing and it is hard to find items you are looking for.

The editor has the nasty habit of adding a column to the left and removing it dynamically based on the item under your mouse. What that does is when you are trying to select text with the mouse, your text switches right and left by one character as you move which makes precise selection a difficult thing to do

Getting in the debugger involves too many steps and it generally moves your files in the editor to the EOF position when you set breakpoints, so you will do a lot of scrolling to go back to the sections of interest.

The debugger output looks fancy with all the graphical elements but it is also cumbersome to operate.

GPS offers better help features for Ada libraries though, it's generally easier to browse the standard libraries and check them out than in Eclipse.

All in all, if Eclipse works for you, you might want to stick with it or perhaps open both on the same project and switch to GPS for things like help etc.

I had a related question out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22576860/what-ada-ides-are-readily-available) which is on hold now (as I expect your question will soon be due to it's broad content) but I did some research and I am generally dissatisfied with what is out there in the Ada field. The language is great but it suffocates under bad tools.

One last tip: You might want to try Slick Edit as it's text editor and browsing features are quite good, although they too have flaws with Ada (for instance the beautifier).

Good luck with your venture

Comment: There's a lot of things unnecessarily awkward in GPS or GNAT Studio as the new version is called. Simple things like a tab that is a dead key by default, inadequate use of mouse functions, automatic indents when you never asked for them, a terrible default code font, inability to select several files to open in a project folder at once, a UI that's as exciting as a funeral-parlor, etc, etc. Some of these can be reconfigured of course. But some are there to stay.